Issue with layout when using Laravel/Vuexy/Select2 for multiple selection
I'm encountering a problem with the layout when using Laravel + Vuexy + Select2 for multiple selection in my project. I followed the documentation closely, but the layout doesn't appear as expected for multiple selection, even though it works fine for single selection.
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="group">{{ __('locale.filters.group') }}:</label>
        <select class="select2 form-select form-select-lg" data-allow-clear="true">
          @foreach ($groupOptions as $groupKey => $groupValue)
          <option value="{{ $groupKey }}" {{ in_array($groupKey, $groups) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{ $groupValue }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>

Example of wrong layout:

Expected layout:

Tried to follow the docs from Select2, no impact at all.
I am using Vuexy html + laravel temlate, select2 / jquery initialized from the box.
/resources/assets/vendor/libs/select2/select2.js

import select2 from 'select2/dist/js/select2.full';

try {
  window.select2 = select2;
} catch (e) {}
select2();

export { select2 };


Finally, i have to put into partial with selects the following:
@section('vendor-style')
@vite([
  'resources/assets/vendor/libs/select2/select2.scss',
])
@endsection

@section('vendor-script')
@vite([
  'resources/assets/vendor/libs/select2/select2.js',
])
@endsection

@section('page-script')
@vite([
  'resources/assets/js/forms-selects.js',
])
@endsection

And after this, everything is working.
